# Issue diplaying Crm reports in an iframe in internet explorer

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, reporting-services, crm

For displaying a report , i created a webresource and hardcoded my report id in it.
Its working fine in chrome and mozzila, but in IE11 am facing this. I even tried to show my report in Dashboards using iframe in crm 2011, but  there also facing same issue.

Here is my webresource code

```
      <HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <title></title>
        <style>
           html, body, iframe {
    margin: 0;
    padding:0;
           }

        </style>
    <script src="../../ClientGlobalContext.js.aspx" ></script>
    <script>
        function SetReport() {
            var id = 'ED7DDF07-1F40-E411-A9B6-00155D1E1F77';
                //qs("data");
            if (!IsGuid(id)) {
                var msg = "Please provide valid id in Web Resource properties dialog.";
                msg += "\n\nMake sure that %7b from beginning and %7d from end are not present in the custom parameter of web resource properties."
                alert(msg);
                return;
            }
            var serverAndOrgUrl = getServerUrl();
            var iframeSrc = serverAndOrgUrl + '/crmreports/viewer/viewer.aspx?action=run&id=%7b' + id + '%7d';
            var report = document.createElement("iframe");
            report.setAttribute('id', 'reportFrame');
            report.setAttribute('name', 'reportFrame');
            report.setAttribute('src', iframeSrc);
            report.setAttribute('height', '450');
            report.setAttribute('width', '100%');
            report.setAttribute('scrolling', 'auto');
            report.setAttribute('frameborder', '0');   


            if (report.addEventListener) {
                report.addEventListener('load', HideControls, true);
            }
            else if (report.attachEvent) {
                report.attachEvent('onload', HideControls);
            }

            var reportDiv = document.createElement("div");
            reportDiv.setAttribute('height', '100%');
            reportDiv.setAttribute('width', '100%');
            reportDiv.setAttribute('id', 'framediv');
            reportDiv.appendChild(report);
            document.body.appendChild(reportDiv);

            function HideControls() {
                menubar = report.contentWindow.document.getElementById('mnuBar1');
                if (menubar != null) {
                    menubar.style.display = "none";
                }

                menubar2 = report.contentWindow.document.getElementById('crmMenuBarmnuBar');
                if (menubar2 != null) {
                    menubar2.style.display = "none";
                }

                editFilter = report.contentWindow.document.getElementById('trEditFilter');
                if (editFilter != null) {
                    editFilter.style.display = "none";
                }

                //Changing the layout for Report control to appear from top.
                resultFrameDiv = report.contentWindow.document.getElementById('divResultFrame');
                if (resultFrameDiv != null) {
                    resultFrameDiv.style.top = "0px";
                }

                //Since getElementsByClassName doesn't work in IE.
                filterViewSpan = getByClass('viewer_td_FilterEditor');
                if (filterViewSpan != null) {
                    filterViewSpan.style.top = "0px";
                }
            }



            //Parses all the div tags
            function getByClass(className) {
                divTags = report.contentWindow.document.getElementsByTagName('div');
                if (divTags == null || divTags == undefined) {
                    return null;
                }
                for (i = 0; i < divTags.length; i++) {
                    if (divTags[i].className == className) {
                        return divTags[i];
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }

            function qs(search_for) {
                var query = window.location.search.substring(1);
                var parms = query.split('&');
                for (var i = 0; i < parms.length; i++) {
                    var pos = parms[i].indexOf('=');
                    if (pos > 0 && search_for == parms[i].substring(0, pos)) {
                        return parms[i].substring(pos + 1);
                    }
                }
                return "";
            }

            function getServerUrl() {
                context = GetGlobalContext();
                return context.getServerUrl();
            }

            function IsGuid(guid) {
                if (guid != null) {
                    var guidRegEx = /^([0-9a-fA-F]){8}-([0-9a-fA-F]){4}-([0-9a-fA-F]){4}-([0-9a-fA-F]){4}-([0-9a-fA-F]){12}$/;
                    return guidRegEx.test(guid);
                }
                return false;
            }
        }
    </script>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY style="margin: 0px" onload="SetReport()" id="iframebody">
    </BODY></HTML>
```

here is the link to the result am getting in IE :-
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzampA1MDINOX3Vac2pJX0Uyc0k/edit?usp=sharing

and result am getting in Chrome:-
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzampA1MDINOa3ZzbGpob1p1bjg/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: which exact issue you get? the report is not displayed at all?

Comment: Hello @GuidoPreite, i just added the screenshot of the issue, you can see now what exact issue am facing.